# How to make codelens references pop in and out less frequently in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've started using VS Code quite a bit recently and I like it; however, I'm getting kind of annoyed with *references*, or rather how frequently they pop in and out. Code hides them when I'm typing, and after about half a second of not typing, they pop up. It's very distracting and annoying, so I was wondering if there was a way to make it less so.

Maybe there would be a way to adjust the delay so it would take maybe 3-5 seconds for the references links to show up? Alternatively, if there is a toggle function for hiding/unhiding references, that would also work for me.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I'm working with java.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your settings you can change the delay before they pop up under the property `editor.quickSuggestionsDelay`

So if you were to add `"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 3000` to your settings file, it would give you a 3 second delay.

Comment: That's not codelens.  That's intellij.  No feature yet found for codelens.